# How to retrieve actual blob data rather than "oracle.sql.blob@" from an Oracle database over JDBC?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, jdbc, jython

We are retrieving data from an oracle database using Jython and JDBC but a BLOB field isn't returning the blob data. Instead of the actual blob data, we are seeing fields that look like this:

> oracle.sql.BLOB@10e8881

If we do the same query in Razor SQL using a JDBC connection, we can see the blobs in the result text and they look fine. (We do not see the "oracle.sql.Blob" in the fields at all.)

This is the Python code and the SQL doing the query:

```
cur = connect_to_database()
query = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE ROWNUM = 1".format(table_name)
cur.execute(query)
results = cur.fetchall()
print results
```

When we print the results, one of the columns has the value we show above. We aren't seeing the binary blob.

Here's how we are executing our Python script:

```
C:\jython2.7.0\bin\jython.exe C:\path_to_our_script.py
```

**How do we get the actual binary data in the blob returned rather than the "oracle.sql.blob@" text we are seeing?**

Comment: That isn't the value of the Blob, it is the default `Object.toString()` of Java. A blob object is just a handle to get data out of a database blob, it is not the value of the blob itself. You would need to call the [`java.sql.Blob`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) methods to get the actual data.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel We seem unable to find that method in the Python SQL library. That appears to be a java library. How is that useable within the Python codebase we are using above?

Comment: You are using JDBC, which is Java-based, but behind some Python wrapper. Check the documentation of that wrapper or contact the author.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an option to upgrade to zxJDBC instead of pure JDBC then you would get support for blob to array conversion out of the box.

```
create table T_BLOB (b BLOB,c INTEGER);
insert into t_blob(b,c) values ( utl_raw.cast_to_raw('test1'),1);
insert into t_blob(b,c) values ( utl_raw.cast_to_raw('test2'),1);
commit;
```

Get blob and int values:

```
from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC

def connect():
    p = {}
    p['URL'] = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@192.168.0.5:1521:dev'
    db = apply(zxJDBC.connectx, ("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource",), p)    
    return db.cursor()

cur = connect()
query = "SELECT * FROM t_blob"
cur.execute(query)
print cur.fetchall()
```

It prints:

```
[(array('b', [116, 101, 115, 116, 49]), 1.0), (array('b', [116, 101, 115, 116, 50]), 1.0)]
```

It works using following versions:

- oracle: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production on Sun Solaris
- java: [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.8.0_231
- jython: Jython 2.7.0 (default:9987c746f838, Apr 29 2015, 02:25:11)
- jdbc: jdbc7.jar (Implementation-Version: 12.1.0.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the binary data to get the text from the blob.

The following code snippet is roughly what you need.

```python
import java.io

# Some code

bs = theBlob.getBinaryStream()
ir = java.io.InputStreamReader(bs)
br = java.io.BufferedReader(ir)

total = ''
st = br.readLine()
while st != None:
   total = total + st
   st = br.readLine()
```

In the above code snippet, the blob gets dumped to the string `total`.

Following is a similar working example of reading from a file.

```python
import java.io

f = java.io.File('test.txt')
fr = java.io.FileReader(f)
br = java.io.BufferedReader(fr)

st = br.readLine()
while st != None:
    print st
    st = br.readLine()
```

Comment: It is unclear to us how we integrate your code into what we are doing above. We don't have a binary stream or a file. We are trying to *get* the binary stream over SQL. What are the hooks that bridge the variables and methods we are using to the code you are suggesting?

Comment: @Praxiteles - The first sample should work. Unfortunately, I didn't have a working blob in hand to test the code. That is why I shared an equivalent file read example to demonstrate what roughly needs to be done. `bs = theBlob.getBinaryStream()` should work since it is a `oracle.sql.BLOB` object.